# How to assemble this headset?

Tags: maintenance, headset

I bought a new threaded headset for my old steel winter beater bike, but it is slightly different from the current one and I am not sure about the correct order and orientation of the parts. I placed the bottommost one on the left.

Is this the correct order?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing the exact model of headset you're installing it's difficult to give a confident yes, however it looks correct. From left to right you have a fork crown race (this gets pressed onto the fork), two head tube cup and bearing assemblies (see below), upper race/dust cap (installed directly onto the upper head tube cup assembly), and finally a lock nut (this should be installed above any spacers you may use). The orientation of the parts in the first photo appears correct as well. If you've never installed a headset [Park Tool have an article on servicing threaded headsets](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/threaded-headset-service) and [Sheldon Brown has an article going over headset types and service procedures](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/headsets.html).

The only unknown is if the two head tube cup assemblies are identical (ie, can be swapped freely) or if there is a specific upper and lower assembly. There should be markings on outer housing or something in the installation instructions to help identify which is which if they came as an upper/lower pair. You may also find that only one fits snugly into the dust cap and the other is loose which would indicate which one to use as the upper.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the exact model since there are no markings on the parts and I got it without the original packaging. The two head tube cup assemblies are identical. I'll try to install it tomorrow. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score -1):

it's depending on what kind of fork shaft you do use.But you will commonly see the lock nut,lock nut is a big bolt,next of lock nut is adjustable race ring which was mounted tightly so you have to use the spring supported pliers to open it.then you will see the bearings.

Comment: Hi Lan. From your various posts to this site I see you don't understand how it works yet. Again: we recommend that new members take the [tour] to make best use of the site, and since you're answering see [answer] also. Regarding the edit to this post, see [expected behavior](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/behavior), and regarding deleted posts see [How and why are some answers deleted?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers)